# jQuery event listener for when text has changed in a <td> cell?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way in jQuery to attach a listener to a `<td>` cell so that when the text inside the cell has changed (by JavaScript, not the user), the event is triggered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To extend [mway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887976/jquery-event-listener-for-when-text-has-changed-in-a-td-cell/3887992#3887992), here is some code.

```
var td = $('#my-table tr td:eq(1)');
var tdHtml = td.html();
setInterval(function() {

    if (td.html() !== tdHtml) {
         // it has changed
         tdHtml = td.html();
    } 

}, 500);
```

... and for his second suggestion.

```
function updateTd(html) {
     $('#my-table tr td:eq(1)').html(html);

     // additional code
}
```

You could also bind the `DOMSubtreeModified` event to the element, but browser support isn't the best.

Comment: Kudos for expanding, it's late. ;)

Comment: If this will work, I think it would be best to check if the length are equal. `if (td.html().length !== tdHtml.length) {..}` Cause I think comparison of numbers has faster performance.

Comment: @Reigel Of course, but what if I update the `innerHTML` to have the same length of chars?

Comment: if that's the case, I'll leave you with this question too. Is `"values" !== "&#118;&#97;&#108;&#117;&#101;&#115;"` ? ;)

Comment: @Reigel Edge cases always welcome :) I guess that will need to be documented, however, it is still a *change*, even if it may not appear to be from the end user's perspective. Also, how often will JavaScript update the `td` with encoded chars?

Comment: @alex. haha nice question. and how many times did it happen to you that you have to change the `length` of `innerHTML` directly. hehe

Comment: @Reigel I think you misunderstood me above `('bob'.length === 'tom'.length)`. That is what I was getting at. Whilst the comparison will be faster, it won't exactly be accurate ;).

Comment: @alex ahh nice catch!.. and what I was thinking too is `if (td.html().length !== tdHtml.length) { changed happened } else if (td.html() !== tdHtml) { changed happened }` so if the length are not equal, no need to check the value of it. ;)

Comment: @Reigel Oh, yeah, I get it. :) Well yes, that *would* be faster, but it smells *micro optimisationy*. I guess it would be useful if your `setInterval` interval was something like 10 microseconds :).

Comment: @alex. haha with `10 microseconds`, I wonder how would it react when the length of the chars to be compared are (let's say) `Thousands` or more. And doing that without using the `comparing of length's` ;)

Comment: Well, that is a lot of characters for a `td`. I wonder how JavaScript stores strings, if it stores the length alongside then it will be much quicker but it will be slow too if it needs to find an end of string character (I don't think it does though).

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected! jQuery makes working in JS so easy that I always forget the basics.

Comment: Does this handle all cases when the content has changed? Does it work if the table was already loaded and the user is changing the content ?

Answer (score 4):

Not natively, no.  You have a couple options:

1) Use `setInterval()` to test the value against its previous value, and act accordingly if it is different.

2) Use a common method for changing the cell contents, such that you can also perform additional logic when its value is changed without rewriting it numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Horrors.  May have been acceptable in 2010.

```
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {

            let target = mutation.target;
            // when the cell is empty, typing a character involves 1 event:
            // target: TD, type childList, addNodes has 1 element
            if( target.constructor.name === 'HTMLTableCellElement' && mutation.type === 'childList' ){
                if( mutation.addedNodes.length == 1 ){
                    if( mutation.addedNodes[ 0 ].constructor.name === 'Text' ){
                        if( mutation.addedNodes[ 0 ].length == 1 ){
                            console.log( `new 1-char Text added, contents: |${mutation.addedNodes[ 0 ].data}|`)

                            // remove "hanging" BR if applicable
// NB this BR gets added automatically when the Text node is removed on 
// becoming empty. You don't want to remove the BR until new text starts
// to be added, because if you remove the BR immediately the cursor goes
// to a funny location in the cell
                            if( target.childNodes.length == 2 ){
                                if( target.childNodes[ 1 ].nodeName === 'BR' ){
                                    target.removeChild( target.childNodes[ 1 ] )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if( target.constructor.name === 'Text' && mutation.type === 'characterData' ){
                console.log( `Text has changed, contents now: |${target.data}|`)
            }

            const cell = target.constructor.name === 'HTMLTableCellElement'? target : target.parentElement
            // respond to the changed text:
            // NB with the "characterData" mutation where cell is null (Text set to empty string), this is followed immediately
            // by another "childList" mutation where the target is the cell...
            if( cell !== null ){
                console.log( `current cell contents |${cell.innerHTML}|`)
            }



       });
    });

    const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData : true, subtree : true };
    observer.observe( htmlTable, config );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input event listener.

> $(document).on( 'input', '#table > tbody > tr >  td',function(){ })