# How to calculate dynamic rows and cells sum value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

its working fine when already values display but i want when change the values in cells sum values also change please help me...

```
$(".prop_inc_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:last-child").text(function(){
                var t = 0;
                $(this).prevAll().each(function(){ 
                    t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
                });
                return t;
            });

            $(".prop_inc_table tr:last td:not(:first,:nth-child(2),:last)").text(function(i){
                var t = 0;
                $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 2)+")").each(function(){
                    t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
                });
                return t;
            });
```

Comment: maybe this answer can inspire you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887976/jquery-event-listener-for-when-text-has-changed-in-a-td-cell