# How to check type of value inserted in HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, contenteditable

I am working on a contenteditable HTML table. I have to assure that only numeric values can be inserted, and show an alert when user tries to insert strings, or something that is not a number. How can I do this? I've searched online but I did not find anything yet.

btw, I use prompts to communicate: is there a way to deny the user to check the option "don't let the browser keep prompting things"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the typeof operator:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp.  Wrap it in an if statement and stop the user from proceeding.

Comment: my problem is to identify the cell in which the user inserts the value. i have a large table, mostly editable... how can i catch the event of the modify?

Comment: I'm going to refer you to a thread here at Stack Overflow that answered this question pretty well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887976/jquery-event-listener-for-when-text-has-changed-in-a-td-cell

Comment: Thanks for the help! i think the best think is to unset the contenteditable tag and create a custom function for inserting values, and checking them too.

Answer (score 0):

use typeof operator -- for example;

```
 var val = your value.
 if('number' == typeof val)
 {
    //your logic
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to handle your DataTable with id, so you can check input type value with js function typeof. Here is an example: [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_datatypes_typeof)

Something like this:

```
var inputVal= document.getElementById("yourTableId");
if('string' == typeof inputVal)
{
  alert("This is a string!");
}
else if('NaN' == typeof inputVal)
{
  alert("This is not number!");
}
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: my problem is to identify the cell in which the user inserts the value. i have a large table, mostly editable... how can i catch the event of the modify? i think IDs are the only way, but i don't know hot to use them... i'm thinking to a polling cycle, but i dont think it is the best way to do this